# Using convert template from Wikipedia throwing Scribunto error

Tags: php, mediawiki, lua, mediawiki-extension

I imported the convert template (Template:convert) from Wikipedia to use on my Wiki; it throws the following error when used:

> Internal Eroror [18eba24f] 2013-07-09 15:00:33: Fatal exception of type ScribuntoException

The Wiki is located here: wiki.tankpedia.org

I had an initial problem early on with the [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) install and I found through research online that I needed to `chmod` the files to be executable so I have set them to 755.

One problem is the distinct generality of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem. I deleted the install I had and installed (with `chmod` 755) the latest Scribunto files from development. I suspect the latest working copies had a patch for the bug I encountered. After doing this I no longer had the error above.